# ¿Cómo utilizar el ID o value de un Select2 Multiple en otro JS?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, select2

He estado trabajando con `Checkbox` sobre un `JS` que me permite ocultar o mostrar lo seleccionado, recientemente he cambiado a un `select2 multiple`, pero tengo problemas al utilizar mi `script` y enlazar lo que se ha seleccionado con lo que se tiene que mostrar.

El código que utilizo con `checkbox` es el siguiente:

```
    <br><div style="margin-bottom: 15px;" align="left"><strong>Areas Participantes:</strong>

  <input name="BEA" id="BEA" value="1" onchange="myFunction('ChEA')" type="checkbox">
  <label>EA</label>  
  <input name="BEK" id="BEK" value="2" onchange="myFunction('ChEK')" type="checkbox">
  <label>EK</label>

</div>
<tr id="ChEA" style="display: none;">
        <td>
    <label>MGEA:</label>
    </td>
        <td>
<input placeholder="Stunden" style="FONT-SIZE: 11; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana; BACKGROUND-COLOR: RGB(201,219,229); width:80px; text-align:center" class="caja" type="text"> 
<input style="FONT-SIZE: 11; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana; BACKGROUND-COLOR: RGB(201,219,229); width:60px; text-align:center" class="caja" value="54.5" type="text">
<input placeholder="SGK" style="FONT-SIZE: 11; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana; BACKGROUND-COLOR: RGB(201,219,229); width:80px; text-align:center" class="caja" type="text" align="top">

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="ChEK" style="display: none;">
        <td>
    <label>MGEK:</label>
    </td>
        <td>
<input placeholder="Stunden" style="FONT-SIZE: 11; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana; BACKGROUND-COLOR: RGB(201,219,229); width:80px; text-align:center" class="caja" type="text"> 
<input style="FONT-SIZE: 11; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana; BACKGROUND-COLOR: RGB(201,219,229); width:60px; text-align:center" class="caja" value="48.5" type="text">
<input placeholder="SGK" style="FONT-SIZE: 11; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana; BACKGROUND-COLOR: RGB(201,219,229); width:80px; text-align:center" class="caja" type="text" align="top">
    </td>
    </tr>
```

y mi `script` es el siguiente:

```
<script>

  function myFunction(id) {
  switch(id)
  {
                case "ChEA": 
                               if (document.getElementById(id).style.display == 'block')
                               {
                                               document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
                               }
                               else
                               {
                                               document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
                               }
                               break;
                case "ChEK": 
                               if (document.getElementById(id).style.display == 'block')
                               {
                                               document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
                               }
                               else
                               {
                                               document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
                               }
                               break;
```

Mi código de `select2` es el siguiente:

```
  <script> 

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.seleccionareas').select2();
    });

  </script>
```

```
      <option value="EA" id="BEA" oninput="myFunction('ChEA')">EA</option>
      <Option Value="EK" id="BEK" oninput="myFunction('ChEK')">EK</option>
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que ocurre es que el evento se lo debes poner a la etiqueta `<select>`, ya que esta es la que cambia su valor realmente (por ejemplo cuando quieres obtener su valor en un formulario), así que podría quedar así:

```
    $( "#selectable").on('change', function(){

       var valueOption = $('#selectable option:selected').val();
                           // $('#selectable option:selected') obtiene el <option></option> que está seleccionado actualmente y con .val() obtengo su valor
       switch(valueOption){
           case "elemento1":
               console.log("entro en elemento1");
               // Aquí pones tu lógica para el <option> con value="elemento"
           break;
          case "elemento2":
              console.log("Entro en elemento2");
          break;
          default:
                 console.log("Entro en otro");
  }

});
```

Y en el HTML:

```
<select id="selectable" >
    <option value="elemento1">opcion 1</option>
    <option value="elemento2">opcion 2</option>
    <option value="elemento4">opcion 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por comentar, perdón pero podrías explicarme cómo puedo aplicar el switch pero ahora en función del valor en atributo, por favor y gracias